# django admin login failure with valid user

Tags: django, django-admin, django-grappelli

I've just created a new django app but am unable to log into the (grappelli) admin with a valid superuser. I've checked the user in the shell -

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> user = authenticate(username='admin', password='admin')
>>> user.is_active and user.is_superuser
True
```

When I enter the same credentials at localhost:8000/admin I get an error message saying 'Please correct the errors below'. However no errors are listed

[image: broken login]

I noticed that there's no session being created in the django_sessions table when I try and login using the browser (there are sessions created for the shell login above).

I'm using django 1.6.2 with grappelli and running this on django's dev webserver.

Comment: Try putting an `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the login view, and see what `form.errors` contains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to login into django admin you should checked below options.

```
is_superuser  is True 
or
is_staff  is True
```

for the user you are login .

*EDIT*
try to uninstall grappelli and then login into django admin.

Comment: Thanks, my user is a superuser.

Comment: try to create a new admin by using command python manage.py createsuperuser   and try to login with new admin account .

Comment: try to uninstall grappelli and then login into django admin

Comment: That's it - tried removing grappelli and logged in fine. Looks like I had the wrong version of grappelli (2.6.1 - it required django 1.7). I've reverted to grappelli 2.5.2. Thanks again (if you want to add this to your answer I'll accept it).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by setting a breakpoint where the login actually happens. Which is here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L371

The `self.has_permission(request)` returned a False, even though in the database `is_staff` was set to `1`. Clearing the cache fixed it for me.

Comment: How do you clear the cache?